# Tabbed Components .NET maui

Tags: .net, maui

Is there a way to make a component with .NET MAUI like this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UnJv.jpg)

I tried to research and look for a way to something like this but all ways say to how to used tabbedpages and tabbar to make the whole page a tabbedpage

Comment: yes you can, give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

We had a discussion about this some time ago. So take a look at this SO [DataBinding for custom ContentView works in Code behind, but not Xaml](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76869113/10528003) It is a working control for a NavBar but you need to add the Commands.