# Binding on Custom BindableProperty not working

Tags: c#, maui

I'm having trouble binding values to a custom `ContentView` I have.

I have a `ContentPage` that uses a `AccountStatusView` that is a `ContentView` and has a `BindableProperty`. This BindableProperty is of type `AccountStatus`. When I try to use binding, the `BindableProperty` is never udpated.

Does someone know why this doesn't work?

**MainPage - xaml**

```xml
<Grid>
    <controls:AccountStatusView AccountStatus="{Binding AccountStatus}" />
</Grid>
```

**MainPage - C#**

```cs
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage(ViewModel vm) {
        BindingContext = vm;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```cs
public partial class ViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty] private AccountStatusDto _accountStatus;
    // . . .
    public async Task InitializeAsync()
    {
        AccountStatus = await _repo.GetAccountStatus();
    }
}
```

**AccountStatusView**

```cs
public partial class AccountStatusView : ContentView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty AccountStatusProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(AccountStatus), typeof(AccountStatusDto), typeof(AccountStatusView), propertyChanged: DoSomething);

    public static void DoSomething(BindableObject bindable, object oldvalue, object newvalue)
    {
        // do something with the new value
    }

    public AccountStatusDto AccountStatus
    {
        get => (AccountStatusDto)GetValue(AccountStatusProperty);
        set => SetValue(AccountStatusProperty, value);
    }

}
```

### EDIT

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73014571/22576603) answer by [ToolmakerSteve](https://stackoverflow.com/users/199364/toolmakersteve),

> When making a custom component (that includes XAML), DO NOT set
> BindingContext = this;

And

> ACCESS COMPONENT PROPERTIES VIA x:Name
>
> Solution: Give the custom component (card) an x:Name, and make that
> the "Source" of those bindings:
>
> ```xml
>     <VerticalStackLayout
>         ...
>         x:Name="me"     <-- IMPORTANT! Change name as desired.
>         x:Class="DataBindingExample.Card">
>         ...
>         <Label Text="{Binding CardIncrement, Source={x:Reference me}}"
>         ...
> ```

And it worked perfectly

Comment: I checked the documentation and they have 'false' before callback in that example. Have you right everything? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/bindable-properties#detect-property-changes

Comment: Yes, that `false` is the default value that you can give to the property. It's optional since the method signature assigns `default` to that parameter

Comment: If you want to set the BindingContext for a ContentView, you could set ```this.Content.BindingContext = new MyViewModel();```

Answer (score 0):

I notice that you have found the solution, and I would like to add a few suggestions.

First, as ToolMakerSteve said that you can give the custom component (card) an x:Name, and make that the "Source" of those bindings:

```
  <VerticalStackLayout
        ...
        x:Name="me"     <-- IMPORTANT! Change name as desired.
        x:Class="DataBindingExample.Card">
        ...
        <Label Text="{Binding CardIncrement, Source={x:Reference me}}"
        ...
```

Second, you can also add the `BindingContext` to the same page in a control like the `VerticalStackLayout`. Then, you can bind the `BindableProperty` to the elements in the page.

```
<ContentView 
             ...
             x:Name="me">

    <VerticalStackLayout BindingContext="{x:Reference me}">
        <Entry x:Name="editAnswer" Text="{Binding  BindableProperty}"> 
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentView>
```